# Contractibility of infinite dimensional spheres and some other infinite dimensional manifolds

Tags: homotopy-theory, banach-spaces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

It is known  that spheres in Banach spaces are contractible according to

Yoav Benyamini, Yaki Sternfeld, "[Spheres in infinite-dimensional normed spaces are Lipschitz contractible](https://doi.org/10.2307/2044990)", Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 88, 439-445 (1983), [MR699410](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=699410), [Zbl 0518.46010](https://zbmath.org/0518.46010).

**Q**: consider the set
$$
\left\{f: f \in C[0,1],\; \int\limits_0^1 f^2(x)\operatorname{d\!}x  =1 \right\},$$
where $C[0,1]$ is the space of continuous functions on [0,1]. (Note that this is not the Banach norm; in fact the space is incomplete in this norm, and we do not wish to complete it with this new norm). Is it contractible? What is an explicit contraction?

**Q**: The same question for the set
$$
\left\{f: f \in C[0,1],\; \int\limits_0^1 f^{2n}(x) dx  =1 \right\}
$$

Comment: What topology are you endowing your sets with?

Comment: Are you just considering the space $C([0,1])$ endowed with the $L_2$-norm? Then it's an infinite-dimensional normed space, so by the theorem from the paper its unit ball is Lipschitz contractible. The paper does not require completeness of the normed space.

Comment: The norm on C([0,1]) is the sup norm ||f|| = sup { |f(x)| }.